# get GNU `ld` to link against static functions in another binary without including them

Tags: c, ld

I have a microcontroller, where i put a big program in ROM, which is supposed to, at a certain point, fetch a payload into RAM and execute it, which then again is supposed to call back into functions in ROM.

The first half (calling into RAM) seemed simple enough:

```
/* ROM linker script */

MEMORY
{
  rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K /* this includes .text */
  ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 10K /* was 20K, cut in half to make space for payload, this includes .data, .bss, etc */
  plram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20002800, LENGTH = 10K /* space for payload */
}

SECTIONS{
  .ramPayloadBlock : {
    __RAM_PAYLOAD_START = .;
    KEEP(*(.ramPayload))
  } > plram
}

// ROM code
extern int __RAM_PAYLOAD_START;
void __attribute__((section (".ramPayload"))) (*ramPayload)(void) = (void(*)(void))&__RAM_PAYLOAD_START; // this works as long as the payload's entrypoint is actually at the start of .ramPayload
ramPayload();
```

but now, when actually linking the code for `ramPayload` I need to somehow tell the linker to look into the ROM's `.map` file or `.elf` binary or whatever to look up the addresses of ROM functions i want to call back into from RAM.

and after hours of looking through the `ld` docs, i have literally no idea how to do that, apart from writing a shell script trying to parse the messy map file and generating a custom header full of function pointers each time, thus reinventing the <s>wheel</s>linker.

Answer (score 2):

ok so i got it to work finally.
the magic linker parameter is `-R rom_binary.elf` (which reads symbols but doesn't include anything from that file).

that and loads of `-E` to make it "export all dynamic symbols" (even though nothing is linked dynamically, which of course isn't documented behaviour so yay)

then just make the linker script for the ram binary locate everything in ram, your entrypoint first (so it neatly gets put at the section start for you to refer to from the ROM code).